# I want to pass label value in "Restrict where this project can be run" field dynamically

Tags: jenkins

I have two freestyle jobs say JOB1 and JOB2. JOB1 has to be run on master while JOB2 to be run on a slave.I have 3 nodes.
Now i want to run my downstream job i.e JOB2 on one of these nodes. One way is to hardcored i.e manually providing the label name in the "restrict where this project can be run"field. However i want that it takes the node automatically where my downstream job  will run.

Isn't there a way to use "Restrict where this project can be run" checkbox and the value will be "%variable%", where 'variable' will hold / is one of the choice parameter's variable's / value. In simple words, why can't value for "Restrict..." allows variable substitution.Simply i want to pass the value in "Restrict where this project can be run" field from a config file .

Note-I have installed NodeLabel Parameter Plugin.Any help would be great thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

Assuming that you upstream job reads the config file (that contains the node name), this variable is going to be passed to the downstream job (JOB2) using ***NodeLabel parameter***

[Upstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj6GI.png)

***myValue*** is the variable that stores the node name taken from the config file.

In the downstream job, you need to have the **Label** parameter configured as below:

[Downstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnPTn.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no support for variables in the "Restrict where this project can be run" box in the job configuration, it needs to be a node name that you have set up in your Jenkins settings.

A workaround for this could be :

2 Jobs, with a .tpl file and some powershell.

1. Get-RestrictedName - This will take in your parameters and then you can access the env variables through powershell to pass to your script which will then run a template for a groovy file with your parameters, and that will become the label() parameter of the DSL, render the template, which will then give you your .groovy file. Then you process that groovy file with job DSL which becomes job 2
2. Build-onRestricted - now your label will state the parameter above and it will be ran on that node.

Unfortunately it's not the easiest thing to do, but if you have templates already for your jobs on Jenkins it shouldn't be too difficult